# Письмо активации открывается только в mail.ru

Tags: php, email

Здравствуйте. Есть проблема. При регистрации нового пользователя ему высылается письмо для активации. Письма приходят, но открывается только в mail.ru. На других почтах (gmail.com, ya) почему то нет. Вот сам код сообщения:

```
$subject = "Подтверждение регистрации";//тема сообщения
$message = "Здравствуйте, ".$name."!\nСпасибо за регистрацию на sitename.ru\nДля входа на сайт используйте свой логин: ".$login."\nПерейдите по ссылке, чтобы активировать ваш аккаунт:\nhttp://sitename/activation.php?login=".$login."&code=".$activation."\nС уважением,\nАдминистрация сайта sitename.ru";//содержание сообщение mail($email, $subject, $message, "Content-type:text/plane; Charset=utf-8\r\n");//отправляем сообщение
```

И еще, как сделать почту с названием своего сайта, например support@sitename.ru Чтобы отправитель был мой сайт, а не почта от моего хостинга mrnix30@columbus.timeweb.ru
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: по почте - это в админке поищи или это у них доп услуга..

Comment: Ясно. А как быть с неправильными сообщениями?

Comment: во первых, нужно использвать urlencode. Во вторых убедитесь в том что текст имеет кодировку UTF-8

Comment: А где прописать этот urlencode? Файл, содержащий это сообщение так же сохранен в utf-8

Comment: ...http://sitename/activation.php?login=".urlencode($login)."&code=".urlencode($activation)."...

Comment: Все равно не работает. Есть только тема письма в gmail и какой то файл noname, который можно загрузить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так я сделал у себя

```
    $subject = "Активация аккаунта на сайте ".$home."";
$regmail = "Здравствуйте ".$login."<br />
Для активации Вашего аккаунта перейдите по ссылке:<br />
<a href='".$home."/signup.php?id=$id_reg&amp;activation=$activation'>".$home."/signup.php?id=".mysql_insert_id()."&amp;activation=$activation</a><br />
Если аккаунт не будет активирован в течении 24 часов, он будет удален.<br />
С уважением, администрация сайта<br />";
$adds="From: \"password@$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]\" <password@$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]>\n";
$adds .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
mail($_POST['email'],'=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=',$regmail,$adds);
```

Comment: Все заработало!!! Vitagame, огромное Вам спасибо!!!